# css menu list with nested lists

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, markup

I'm trying to recreate this type ([example 1](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-menu-list-design/), [example 2](http://www.search-this.com/2007/11/26/css-a-recipe-for-success/)) of menu list style,  but I need it to be able to handle nested lists and I'm not sure how to do it.  does anyone have any insight how I can do this?

ie (w/ minimal markup) :

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
    <ul>
      <li>two and half</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what styles you're trying to apply, but I can get you started with empty CSS rules for each level:

- `ul { /* CSS properties here */ }` will let you style all `ul` elements
- `ul > li > ul { ... }` will override the applied CSS style for the inner `ul` elements, because the selector has a higher [specificity](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/)
- Likewise, for the `li` elements, use the rule `li { ... }` for the outer `li` elements, and
- `ul > li > ul > li { ... }` for the inner `li` elements

Does that help?

Comment: kind of. This will be a tree with sub-levels, sub-sub-levels, etc...  But I need some links on the right hand side to all line up, irregardless of the level.  I'm not much of a CSS guru, but I do understand the higher weight for the more specific rules.  just trying to figure out how to get a child tree to play nicely.  might be over my head.

Comment: You might be able to pull it off with relative positioning (and other CSS) applied to every child `ul` (or its `li` children) so that you don't have to explicitly set whatever you need at every level. I wonder if you might not be better off using a library for this?